# equivalent for mb_convert_encoding() in perl

Tags: php, perl, utf-8

I need to remove windows characters from a csv file before parsing into a database. These are characters like the "long hyphen" or "word inverted commas"

In php I can remove with mb_convert_encoding(), How can I do the same in perl ?

I need to remove only windows characters , not utf-8 characters

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding()` does not "remove" characters; it converts between two encodings. And you first need to know your input and output encodings. Also, what's a "Windows" character and why is it a problem if you accept the rest of the Unicode catalogue?

Answer (score 1):

The `from_to()` function from [Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) seems to be a pretty close match for [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode).

But it sounds like you have a file where some of it is encoded in [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and some of it is in [UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). That seems strange and I'm not sure how you'd tell which bit of the file has each encoding.