# Remove windows character (�) from file or string from php/perl

Tags: php, perl

I want to remove windows junk character(�) from *csv* file and maintain *utf* characters.
I tried below things but did not work.

```
mb_convert_encoding.
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\s]/u','',$str);
utf8_encode
```

Comment: This looks very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216268/equivalent-for-mb-convert-encoding-in-perl/33218899). Are you two working together?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

It will remove invalid characters.